# nginx regex redirect gives extra slash

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I plan to convert this address:
`www.somewebsite.com/news/22915`

To this address:
`www.somewebsite.com/news/22915.html`

And this is how I do it in my nginx configuration:
`rewrite ^/news/(\d+)$ /news/$1\.html redirect;`

But somehow, nginx will rewrite my address to:
`www.somewebsite.com/news/22915/.html`

Had no idea why / will go into the variable automatically, since (\d+) should only be matching pure numbers, need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rewrite ^/news/(\d+)$ /news/$1.html redirect;`

The second part of the rewrite syntax is not a regex. So you should not try to escape the dot character.

Comment: Thank you! Never came to my mind that second part of it was not regex... since its original .htaccess file are using the escape. Thanks again!